# How to measure Android WebView inbound/outbound traffic

Tags: android, networking, uiwebview, webview, web-traffic

Is it possible to measure Android WebView inbound/outbound traffic?

My task is to measure all network activity performed by my app. As far as I understood TrafficStats class has serious limitations. It may not work under some circumstances. And it also appeared only in API 8, whereas I have to support 7 also. So using it is an option for me only for the case when I won't find any other solution.

Note, that all other network traffic is easily measured, as it is controlled by my app. so the problem is only that part that is issued/received by WebView component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to measure Android WebView inbound/outbound traffic?

Use `TrafficStats`, or use something outside of your device (e.g., some proxy server that can record this information).

> As far as I understood TrafficStats class has serious limitations.

You are certainly welcome to your opinion.

> And it also appeared only in API 8, whereas I have to support 7 also.

Unless you have significantly different behavior in your app specific to API Level 7, the bandwidth consumed by your `WebView` probably does not change much. Set your build target to API Level 8 and use `TrafficStats` on API Level 8+ devices (by means of a `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` check).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It helped. By "limitations" i meant that the class is accessible only after API8 and also that sometimes methods can return UNSUPPORTED in case when device does not support the statistics. I will switch off traffic counting for API < 8 devices.